# JS returns undefined though I have a variable value set

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a code which will pull the data from mysql and display with a check box. On clicking the check boxes it will give the sum in total.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name=check[] value="<?php echo $row['amount'];?>" data-weight="<?php echo $row['amount'];?>"> </td>
<div>Total: <span id="total">0</span></div>
```

and JS is

```
<script>
    (function () {
          var totalEl = document.getElementById('total'),
              total = 0,
              checkboxes = document.form1['check[]'],
              handleClick = function () {
                  total += parseInt(this['data-weight'], 10) * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
                  totalEl.innerHTML = total;
                  alert (this['data-weight']);
              },
              i, l
          ;
          for (i = 0, l = checkboxes.length; i < l; ++i) {
              checkboxes[i].onclick = handleClick;
          }
      }());
    </script>
```

But always I get the result as undefined in alert(which I have added for debugging purpose) and total as NaN. What is that I am doing wrong??

Comment: @MikeChristensen: No, `this` does definitely **not** refer to the function itself (it never does, unless you *explicitly* do it, which is very rare). Since it's used as event handler, `this` will refer to the DOM element. How `this` works is explained at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: @FelixKling is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is that I am doing wrong?

You are not accessing the `data-*` attribute correctly (`this['data-weight']`). DOM elements have a specific set of properties and not all HTML attributes map to DOM properties 1:1. `data-*` attributes certainly don't.

You can use [**`getAttribute`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) to get the value of the attribute:

```
this.getAttribute('data-weight')
```

Alternatively you can use the [**`dataSet`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) property:

```
this.dataSet.weight
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zhrt74pL/)

---

The total is `NaN` because `parseInt(undefined, 10)` returns `NaN`, so any further computation will result in `NaN`.